# Перевод вопроса, начинающегося с surely

Tags: перевод, отрицание, синтаксис

> Surely his wish had not been fulfilled?

В «Портрете Дориана Грея» Оскара Уайльда это предложение передает удивление, испытанное Дорианом Греем после некоторого события. В примечаниях к одному из изданий романа сказано, что такой вопрос следует перевести как «Неужели его желание осуществилось?», однако, очевидно, в языке источника представлено отрицание, тем более что *surely* — в отличие, например, от *hardly* — обладает вполне «утвердительной» семантикой.

Интересно, как добиться большей точности перевода, использовав отрицание и в русском языке, сохранив при этом структуру и применив русские аналоги лексем исходного предложения?

Важно учесть, что Дориан Грей вовсе не предполагал, что его желание вообще может осуществиться. Претворение его в жизнь, которое, как показалось Грею, случилось, было пугающим, а вовсе не приятным.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю почему нельзя сказать "неужто его желание **не** осуществилось?"

Comment: @shabunc думаю, потому, что нельзя сказать _Ты не придешь_ вместо _Ты придешь_ — это разные фразы ;)

Comment: _Не могло же его желание осуществиться!_

Comment: "[И не зови меня Ширли.](https://www.shmoop.com/quotes/dont-call-me-shirley.html)" - честно говоря, сложно поддается переводу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В переводе точность передачи смысла не всегда соответствует схожести грамматических конструкций. Вариант "Неужели его желание осуществилось?" в этом отношении вполне возможен. Это нормальный русский язык, но точность такого перевода должна проверяться контекстом. 
https://www.shmoop.com/picture-dorian-gray/transformation-quotes-2.html

Звучит предложенный в комментарии вариант так, будто персонаж до последнего момента жил тем желанием. Из контекста же следует, что он о нём забыл и, лишь увидя портрет, вспомнил, что искренне высказал его в какой-то момент из прошлого. Несмотря на видимые признаки, не верилось, что забытое желание могло осуществиться, поскольку "такого не бывает". Поэтому здесь выражается смутное сомнение и приблизительный *смысл* (он может быть передан с отрицанием) таков:

> Можно ли быть уверенным, что его желание не осуществилось?

**P.S.** Ещё вариант с тем же смыслом:

> Уж не осуществилось ли его желание?

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция

> "Surely [noun/pronoun] [verb with negation]"

подразумевает уверенность говорящего, что происходящее/произошедшее нереально и невозможно, но в то же время передаёт смятение/удивление, поскольку это всё-таки происходит/произошло.

> Surely this can't be happening? 
> Surely his wish had not been fulfilled? 
> Surely he can't be dating Victoire?

Можно сказать, что человек пытается отрицать реальность (the confused human being is in denial). Перевести эту конструкцию на русский язык можно несколькими способами (кроме уже упомянутых в других ответах):

> **Surely his wish had not been fulfilled?**
>
> - Но ведь его желание не осуществилось, так ведь/не так ли/верно? (ох как часто эти "хвостики" в конце предложений выручают переводчиков!)
> - Но не могло же его желание осуществиться? (вариант, похожий на тот, что был предложен 
>    @J-mster в комментарии, и он, по-моему, самый удачный)
> - Не может быть, чтоб его желание осуществилось!
> - Но ведь его желание никак не могло осуществиться, верно?
> - Но его желание точно не могло осуществиться!

Впрочем, наиболее часто эта конструкция действительно переводится без отрицания, вместо него используется для усиления эффекта изумления частица *неужели*, как и заметил автор вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В слове **неужели** отрицание уже содержится **`"Не уже ли его желание осуществилось?"`** в осовремененном синтаксисе **`"Не осуществилось ли уже его желание?"`**, но в такой форме у предложения нет риторического подтекста.

Перефразировав, можно перевести как **`Не это ли и есть осуществление его желания?`**, правда тут не обошлось без изменения главных членов.

или (как было предложено в комментариях)

**`А точно/действительно ли его желание не осуществилось?`** (подразумевая `а может быть всё-таки осуществилось?`), хотя мне лично такой вариант перевода меньше импонирует.

Comment: Идея остроумная, но все-таки в _неужели_ нет никакого отрицания: если оно когда-то и было, семантика давно затерлась. _Не осуществилось ли уже его желание?_ — это мне напоминает вопрос: «Не закипел еще чайник?» Речь идет не о чем-то действительно желаемом, а о том, что его желание, которое совсем нереально, пугающим образом претворилось в жизнь. Стоит указать это в вопросе. _Не это ли и есть осуществление его желания?_ — неплохо, спасибо, но и синтаксис другой, и surely нет...

Comment: возможно в русском языке сочетание отрицания с наречием, выражающим определённость, не создаёт достаточно убедительного утверждения, например в предложении **`А точно/действительно ли его желание не осуществилось?`** (подразумевая `а может быть всё-таки осуществилось?`) которое по-моему наиболее лексически близко английскому и в котором, так же как и в английском, под вопросом находится наречие

Comment: Вот в таком виде это куда более приемлемо; дополните ответ, а я поставлю галочку.

Comment: вам он нравится? но он же не является адекватным переводом оригинала

Comment: Что не русский язык? Мне кажется, что «(А) точно ли его желание не осуществилось?» вполне подходит под ситуацию: Грей, как бы начиная паниковать, переспрашивает сам себя: «Может, все-таки осуществилось?» :) Кажется, чего-то лучшего придумать не получится (если все-таки получится, передам галочку тому отвечающему).

Comment: сперва неудачно выразился, ну так уж и быть